# how to bind wpf combo box to all system font size

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, font-size

Is there any easy way (or no so easy )
to bind wpf combo box to all system font size?
I would like to do this in the xaml.cs file rather than the straight XAML.

Comment: What is "all system font size"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no such a thing as System Font Sizes. The size could be anything. If you want to use system fonts you could go through those like that:

```
foreach (FontFamily F in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies) addToComboBox(F);
```